# when to specify providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" in a connection string

Tags: connection-string, sqlclient

I had an issue with a Windows service running under `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SYSTEM` whereby the service could not connect to a database.

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.
```

The only difference between the connection string specified for this particular service and another service running under the same account was that the `providerName` attribute was missing. Once I added

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

to the connection string the service could access the database. Can anyone explain why this would be? I thought System.Data.SqlClient was the default provider.

Comment: How are you using this connection string? SqlConnection, DbContext...?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use the SQLClient provider to manager the connection.
SQLClient provider manages connections to Microsoft SQL Servers.

[Here is a code example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3379/connection-strings-in-web-config-file-using-asp-net.aspx)

You never **have** to specify it though, as  its also the [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/htw9h4z3(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for the provider.